# How to compile/install apache2 with configuration of existing apache2?

Tags: linux, apache2

I'm trying to do a minor apache2 upgrade on an old Linux machine. From 2.2.3 to 2.2.29 to be precise. The current version was installed from deb package (meaning there's no config.nice). I want to compile and install the new version from source.

If I do "apache2 -V" on the old installation I get (amongst other things):

```
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT=""
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/apache2/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
```

How can I compile the new version with these options?

Answer (score 0):

Build yourself from the deb-src and fish out the config.nice.

Comment: Thanks, I did just that but after running ./configure, the only thing contained in the config.nice file was this:

`#
# Created by configure

"./configure" \
"$@"
`

Comment: Actually I didn't compile correctly. But I got the compile options from debian/rules.